# 301 redirect htaccess on a database driven website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have created a website using IPB which I believe is written in PHP.

i am trying to use a 301 prominent redirect but when ever I try to use any from around the web I get a 500 server error

the broken url is 'http://thereviewforum.com/index.php?/page/index.html/_/monthly-top-10/top-10-free-vpn-service-providers-r17'

and I would like to direct users and search bots to 
http://thereviewforum.com/monthly_top_10.html/_/monthly-top-10/top-10-free-vpn-service-providers-r17

again any help with be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do **(The following does not work. See below for working example):**

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?/page/index.html/_/monthly-top-10/top-10-free-vpn-service-providers-r17 http://thereviewforum.com/monthly_top_10.html/_/monthly-top-10/top-10-free-vpn-service-providers-r17
```

**Edit:**

You are right the above does not work. I guess query strings aren't considered. I should have tested it first. Here is an example that I tested to make sure it worked.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/page/index.html/_/monthly-top-10/top-10-free-vpn-service-providers-r17$
RewriteRule .? /monthly_top_10.html/_/monthly-top-10/top-10-free-vpn-service-providers-r17 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work for me. I think that is more for static pages

Comment: You are right. My first example didn't work. I should have tested it first!. Anyway I added a working version. I actually tested it on my system.